# I Want To Display The ImagesUrl's In The Array according To The Number of images the Array has, using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-responsive-carousel

I am using React Carousel from The dependency *react-responsive-carousel* to display the image the user has uploaded on firebase I query the images in an Array Like:

```
image: [imageUrl/0, imageUrl/1, imageUrl/2, imageUrl/3, imageUrl/4] // Maximum is 5
    //then display it like 
<Carousel 
         infiniteLoop
         showStatus={true}
         showIndicators={true}
         showThumbs={true}
     >
         <div>
         <img src={imagesUrl[0]} alt="title"/>  
         </div>   
         <div>
         <img src={imagesUrl[1]} alt="title"/> 
         </div>
         <div>
         <img src={imagesUrl[2]} alt="title"/> 
         </div>
         <div>
         <img src={imagesUrl[3]} alt="title"/> 
         </div>
         <div>
         <img src={imagesUrl[4]} alt="title" />
         </div>
     </Carousel>
```

It Works fine But when the user uploaded 3 images it will show 5 images the last 2 will be blank white images, is it possible to Map the Array in a way I only show what is in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can loop over the images and show them:

**using map:**

```js
...
images.map((image) => {
    return <div>
        <img src={image} alt="title" />
    </div>
})
...
```